# FSUTIL HARDLINK CREATE ERROR: ACCESS IS DENIED

Tags: windows-8.1, permissions, cmd.exe, mklink, fsutil

Trying to create hardlink to a folder in the same directory, on the same drive.

```
H:\ParentFolder>fsutil hardlink create fldr01hrdlnk folder01
Error: Access is denied
H:\ParentFolder>fsutil hardlink create %cd%\fldr01hrdlnk %cd%\folder01
Error: Access is denied
```

`mklink /H` doesn't work too.
User has full control and ownership of `ParentFolder` and it's subfolders and files. Inheritance disabled. User is in Administrators. Drive is formatted to `NTFS`. `hardlink` command works for files, like `.txt`, but not for folders. Windows 8.1. How to fix? Is it even possible to create a hardlink to a folder?

Comment: open the cmd.exe as admin

Comment: lol. It is already running "as admin" because I did it myself, tyvm

Comment: even with user in admin group no longer means admin rights since Vista when UAC is active. also moving uac slider down doesn't disable UAC since Win8

Comment: But user is Admin himself.

Comment: again, with UAC activated this doesn't matter.

Comment: You might not be running an elevated command prompt even if you are logged in as Administrator unless you specifically right click from a Command Prompt icon and "Run as Administrator."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"fsutil hardlink create" works only with files. To create a link to a folder (Junction) on the same drive, you can use something like "mklink /J e:\xample e:\xisting\folder", which will create a link named "xample" in the drive "e:". Navigating this link you will enter into "e:\xisting\folder". You can see some Junctions at work in the Operating System, such as "C:\Documents and Settings" which is a Junction to "C:\Users", for example.